# Mercurial Missing Revlog

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm receiving a "missing revlog" error when using Mercurial (via TortoiseHg). Does anybody know how to fix this repo?

```
% hg --repository C:\Source\Project verify --verbose
repository uses revlog format 1
checking changesets
checking manifests
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests
checking files
data/MyProject.Class.Library.Tests/Part/FileName.cs.orig.i@1: missing revlog!
1: empty or missing MyProject.Class.Library.Tests/Part/FileName.cs.orig
MyProject.Class.Library.Tests/Part/FileName.cs.orig@1: fb25dd9d5f41 in manifests not found
4384 files, 1354 changesets, 12803 total revisions
3 integrity errors encountered!
(first damaged changeset appears to be 1)
[command returned code 1 Wed May 11 13:31:14 2011]
```

Comment: It's no help for this time, but there's a good hint as to what caused this.  The mercurial `revert` command creates `.orig` files that go in your working directory, but not your repository.  If someone accidentally committed one you ended up with one down in your `.hg/data` area.  That's fine, but if then someone outside of Mercurial deleted all `.orig` files recursively thinking they'd only be in the working dir they deleted the file down in `.hg/data` too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try to use convert extension with `convert.hg.ignoreerrors` set to True, as described [on the wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RepositoryCorruption#Repository_corruption). Keep in mind that this will modify the hashes, and damaged files will probably be lost completely.

Answer (score 5):

The Mercurial wiki has a page on [Repository Corruption](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RepositoryCorruption#Reconstructing_missing_revlogs).  If the solution suggested by @Cat Plus Plus does not work for you, then you may attempt to reconstruct the revlog.

There is a section with step-by-step instructions for reconstructing missing revlogs.  However, you must have a copy o the problem file as it existed in the "bad" revision.

In your case, you would need an exact copy of `data/MyProject.Class.Library.Tests/Part/FileName.cs.orig` as it existed in revision 1 of the repo.