# Repair mercurial repository because of local missing files

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have a local Mercurial repository that I am managing using TortoiseHg. Being new to Mercurial, I deleted some compiled files in the bin and obj folder of my project from the local file system. Now the repository is corrupt and gives me the message of missing files in the commit dialog. Verify also fails with the list of missing files.

Here is the tail of the log ...

```
data/ApplicationServices/bin/Common.DataServices.Oracle.xml.i@56: missing revlog!
 56: empty or missing ApplicationServices/bin/Common.DataServices.Oracle.xml
 ApplicationServices/bin/Common.DataServices.Oracle.xml@56: 01e844a32962 in manifests not found
 data/ApplicationServices/bin/Common.DataServices.xml.i@56: missing revlog!
 56: empty or missing ApplicationServices/bin/Common.DataServices.xml
 ApplicationServices/bin/Common.DataServices.xml@56: baa0e6eb9bca in manifests not found
 data/ApplicationServices/bin/Common.Entities.xml.i@56: missing revlog!
 56: empty or missing ApplicationServices/bin/Common.Entities.xml
 ApplicationServices/bin/Common.Entities.xml@56: 1e7cf00250c0 in manifests not found
 data/ApplicationServices/obj/Debug/ApplicationServices.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt.i@56: missing revlog!
 56: empty or missing ApplicationServices/obj/Debug/ApplicationServices.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
 ApplicationServices/obj/Debug/ApplicationServices.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt@56: fd28009f3e6e in manifests not found
 data/Entities/obj/Debug/Entities.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt.i@56: missing revlog!
 56: empty or missing Entities/obj/Debug/Entities.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
 Entities/obj/Debug/Entities.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt@56: e2ba293498ed in manifests not found
 Entities/obj/Debug/Entities.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt@60: dd903e8946a9 in manifests not found
 Entities/obj/Debug/Entities.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt@61: 7d60f0cd952f in manifests not found
 data/UnitTests/obj/Debug/UnitTests.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt.i@56: missing revlog!
 56: empty or missing UnitTests/obj/Debug/UnitTests.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
 UnitTests/obj/Debug/UnitTests.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt@56: c0c8cbccba02 in manifests not found
3999 files, 62 changesets, 5710 total revisions
1266 integrity errors encountered!
```

Any chance of removing the missing files from the repository?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to commit? Removing files is a common task with mercurial.

Comment: You'll find useful informations in this other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970648/mercurial-missing-revlog.